External HDD (1 EXT4 Partition) Won't Show Up On Other Linux Computer
I have recently formatted a Seagate 2TB portable HDD with 1 EXT4 partition (from my laptop running arch). When attempting to access this on my PopOS desktop, the drive will not show up in the file manager or disk tools. Additionally, if I try to boot the computer when the drive is plugged in, the computer will hang on the cryptsetup screen. If I try to reboot the computer when the drive is plugged in, the computer hangs there on a black screen until the disk is unplugged.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Seems to be a cryptsetup issue. See https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/bnrx1s/stuck_at_cryptsetup_cryptdata_set_up_successfully/ and https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/1048 . Or consider alternative encryption, e.g., VeraCrypt.
